# Syntax Highlighting for plain text (Sublime Text)

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext2, plaintext

I am a great fan of syntax highlighting in any form. But i am missing something similar for plain text files. Imagine different colors for indented lines or lines preceded by special chars. Does anything like that already exist? I'd especially appreciate a plugin for Sublime Text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest thing I know of is the PlainTasks plugin:

[image: PlainTasks screenshot]

It's a plugin to make styled TODO lists, but what you see in the screenshot is basically it.

You could modify the Markdown or reStructuredText files to actually color the text.

Comment: thanks for your reply. colored markdown is indeed a nice idea

Comment: could you elaborate on how to modify syntax highlighting configurations?

Comment: I don't know how to modify syntax highlighting configs yet, but I don't think it'll be hard to learn if you look as other languages' configurations. It's just XML if I recall correctly.

Comment: Did you ever find anything that satisfied your needs? I'm looking for something similar, closest I've found so far is [this post on the Sublime forum](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=15466) but the referenced download has been removed.